# "lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

Tags: c, lvalue

Looked through the other questions involving the same error but don't quite understand why I'm getting the error.

I'm trying to assign an equation to a variable within a function of the same name?

I'm new to this so if anyone could explain to me why this is happening that would be awesome.

The fifth line from the bottom is where I'm getting the error

```
#define DAYS_PER_WEEK 7

#define THURSDAY 0
#define FRIDAY   1
#define SATURDAY 2
#define SUNDAY   3
#define MONDAY   4
#define TUESDAY  5
#define WEDNESDAY 6

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define DAYS_PER_WEEK 7

int dayOfWeek (int doomsday, int leapYear, int month, int day);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

   dayOfWeek(SUNDAY, FALSE, 1, 10);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int dayOfWeek (int doomsday, int leapYear, int month, int day) {
   if (month == 1) {
      int doomsDate = 4;
      dayOfWeek = (day + doomsDate)/DAYS_PER_WEEK);
      printf ("The day of the week is: =%d\n",dayOfWeek);
   }
   return dayOfWeek;
 }
```

So after @Gopi explained why I changed the function to this

```
int dayOfWeek (int doomsday, int leapYear, int month, int day) {
   if (month == 1) {
      int doomsDate = 4;
      int dayNum = (day + doomsDate)/DAYS_PER_WEEK;
      printf ("The day of the week is: =%d\n",dayNum);
   }
   return dayOfWeek;
}
```

I need to satisfy the following assert:

```
assert (dayOfWeek (SUNDAY, FALSE, 1, 10) == SATURDAY);
```

how would I go about doing that...

Comment: Why don't you just `return dayNum;` ?

Comment: While there are (or were) languages that allow you to assign the result of a function to a variable with the same name as the function (Pascal and Fortran 77, IIRC), C is not a language that allows that.  If you're going to do it (and please don't), you have to declare a local variable with the same name as the function.  For example, this (somewhat to my surprise) compiles under extremely stringent compilation options: `int x(int y);
int x(int y) { int x = y + 2; return x; }` is clean with `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror -pedantic -c x.c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dayOfWeek = (day + doomsDate)/DAYS_PER_WEEK);
```

`dayOfWeek` is a function name so it can't be an assignable lvalue.

> I'm trying to assign an equation to a variable within a function of
>   the same name?

There is no variable `dayOfWeek` within function `dayOfWeek()`.

Comment: @OnlyHughman Please note the difference between a variable and a function name. From function dayOfWeek() you can just return the value using `return dayNum;` You code looks ok until `return dayOfWeek;` which makes no sense because as already said there is no variable dayOfWeek.. I am saying about the previous comment which you deleted the code was right there

Answer (score 0):

*Before Edit:*

Please do not assume there will be any variable automatically defined *inside* a function. It has to be defined either in the parameter (list) or in the function body.

Also, a *function* name is **not** a variable. It's not *lvalue*.

<sup>P.S - Not considering globals</sup>

---

*After edit:*

> I want it to return dayOfWeek and I want it to be the same as dayNum... how could I do this?

In the edited code, `return dayOfWeek;` is not valid as there is no variable called `dayOfWeek;`. You need to (and have to) write

```
 return dayNum;
```